# How do I drag & drop files into a JTable?

Tags: java

I'd like to drag and drop external files (e.g. from windows explorer) into a JTable.  Anybody got some example code as how this is done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply use the DropTarget class to receive drop events. You can distinguish between drops into the current table (available columns/rows) and into the scroll pane (to e.g. add new rows)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class SwingTest extends JFrame{
    private JTable table = new JTable();
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    private DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"a","b","c"},2);

    public SwingTest() {
        table.setModel(tm);
        table.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(){
            @Override
            public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                Point point = dtde.getLocation();
                int column = table.columnAtPoint(point);
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                // handle drop inside current table
                super.drop(dtde);
            }
        });
        scroll.setDropTarget(new DropTarget(){
            @Override
            public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                // handle drop outside current table (e.g. add row)
                super.drop(dtde);
            }
        });
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(scroll);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't do anything except showing the table. When dragging to it , nothing happens

Comment: For empty table the handler for scroll is called, and this implementation of it just calls super.drop. You need to add something there to see it executing.

Answer (score 8):

@yossale You need to add the following code to the method :

```
public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde)      
{
                dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();
                List fileList = (List)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                File f = (File)fileList.get(0);
                table.setValueAt(f.getAbsolutePath(), row, column);
                table.setValueAt(f.length(), row, column+1);
  }
```

Instead of setting you can append rows to the table upon validating that data is not duplicate and add the file info as new rows to table.